# ruby method not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a basic grocery list application in Rails. Each "item" has two properties: name and checked. Name is just the name of the item. Checked is supposed to indicate whether the user has "checked off" the item on their grocery list.

I put a simple method in my item controller to address this. The problem is the method will only change false to true. It will not reverse and allow me to uncheck items.

Here is the method, which is inside my item controller:

```
  def checked 
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if !@item.checked
        @item.update(checked: :true) 
    else
        @item.update(checked: :false)
    end 
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

This will only work for the false to true conversation. The second half of the if statement does not appear to be working. Thoughts?

Comment: A simpler way: `@item.update(checked: !@item.checked?)` -- Your code does not work because it is actually sending a `symbol` object instead of `true` or `false`, remove that semi-colon in front of `true` and `false` and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you want to use symbols `:true` and `:false` there?

I would like to believe `checked` to be a boolean field and boolean equivalents in Ruby are `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the underlying reason (maybe using `#update`), but I'd be trying to code this more like:

```
def checked 
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  if @item.checked
      @item.update_attributes(checked: false) 
  else
      @item.update_attributes(checked: true)
  end
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

... or ...

```
def checked 
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @item.update_attributes(checked: !@item.checked)
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Edit: as @MrYoshiji comments, use `true` instead of `:true` etc